# Modify left join clause

Tags: sql, impala

I am trying to write an impala query that does the follows with two tables provided below:

Table A

```
Date     num
01-16    10
02-20    12
03-20    13
```

Table B contains everyday between 02-20 and 03-20 exclusively, i.e.

```
Date     val
02-21    100
02-22    101
02-23    102
  .       .
  .       .
03-19    110
```

And now we want to calculate everyday the total value between 02-20 and 03-20 exclusively using the A.num of date 02-20(starting date of the period). So for example, the total value of 02-21 is 100*12, 02-22 is 101*12, and 03-19 is 110*12.

I have written the query

`SELECT A.Date,A.num*B.val AS total
 FROM TableA A 
 LEFT JOIN Tableb B
 ON B.Date >= A.Date
 GROUP BY A.Date,A.num,B.val`

But it returns me two entries for each day. For instance, on **02-20**, it will return **101*12** and **101*10**, but I only want 101*12. I have noticed that this is caused by the join on B.Date >= A.Date where 02-21 is indeed greater than 01-16, so it takes both value of num at 01-16 and 02-20 to compute the total value.

Anyone know how should I modify this join clause so it would only use the num on 02-20 only instead of 02-20 and 01-16?

**EDIT**

Sample output

```
Date     total
02-21    1200
02-22    1212
02-23    1224
  .       .
  .       .
03-19    1320
```

Comment: which data type is Date column  .. ??

Comment: timestamp, it should be 01-16-15, but i am just too lazy to write them all out

Comment: Simply remove the a.num and b.val from your group by to get one result per date. Also, add an aggregation function to your formula in the select list. You could use sum() or min() or max depending on the actual data in your table.

Comment: why you have mysql tag ?

Comment: Why do you want an aggregation function in the select?

Comment: Because of the group by. See my answer below. Did you try it?

Comment: @JamesXiang, you no longer have the same test data as in your previous question. This makes no sense and I am starting to wonder if you're serious about your questions here at SO or if you are just throwing out questions without caring about the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. If need be, change the SUM to either MIN or MAX.

```
SELECT A.`Date`,SUM(A.`num`*B.`val`) AS `total`
FROM `TableA` A 
LEFT JOIN `Tableb` B
    ON B.`Date` >= A.`Date`
GROUP BY A.`Date`
```

Comment: No idea from the OP, so that's why I offered the options....

Comment: Using group by on `A.date` will result in only three rows, while the expected result needed more than that, so the `group by` should be on `B.date`.  Check my answer.

Comment: This doesn't work, how can it be marked as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

This produces the results you need. I didn't see a need for `GROUP BY`, and you said you only wanted results for the date '02-20', so I just added a `WHERE` and changed the `SELECT` to grab Table B's date.

```
SELECT
    B.Date,
    A.num * B.val AS total
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN Tableb B ON B.Date >= A.Date
WHERE A.Date = '02-20'
```

Comment: With the expected result, it seem obvious that multiple rows will match.

Comment: Also, this won't work because the OP may have multiple day matches.

Comment: Checking for distinct dates in Table A was not a requirement. It does work, by the way. Create test tables with the OP's data and run it.

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTE :**  You should avoid using `reserved keywords` as table/column name.

Well here you go..

```
SELECT b.`date`,max(a.`num`*b.`val`) AS `total`
FROM test a 
LEFT JOIN `test2` b
    ON b.`date` >= a.`date`
WHERE b.date is not null
GROUP BY b.`dates`;
```

**sqlfiddle**  : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55c0e1/1